# Getting list of available fonts as combo box in javascript

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I need to get a list of all available fonts to present them under a combo box. 
When  a user selects a font -> the selected text should change as a result of its selection. 
My problem is that i do not find a full list which contains all fonts i got by using chrome browser as example.

I mean family fonts that i do not need to download for example "David", "Times New Roman", etc?

Where should i get such a detailed list.

My implementation:

```
 var getFontsFamily = function () {
    var fonts = [];

    var cursiveFont = new ComboBoxElement("cursive", "cursive");
    fonts.push(cursiveFont);

    var fantasyFont = new ComboBoxElement("fantasy", "fantasy");
    fonts.push(fantasyFont);

    var initialFont = new ComboBoxElement("initial", "initial");
    fonts.push(initialFont);

    var monospaceFont = new ComboBoxElement("monospace", "monospace");
    fonts.push(monospaceFont);

    var sanSerifFont = new ComboBoxElement("sans-serif", "sans-serif");
    fonts.push(sanSerifFont);

    var serifFont = new ComboBoxElement("serif", "serif");
    fonts.push(serifFont);

    return fonts;
};
```

In my controller:
$scope.fonts = helperCtrl.getFontsFamily();

And in my html:

```
 <div class="customizedSelect">
    <select id="groupSelection" 
ng-model="selectedText.fontFamily" ng-options="font.type as font.value for font in fonts"></select>
 </div>


<div ng-class="{bold : item.isBold == true}" style="color:{{item.textColor}}; font-size:{{item.size}}pt; font-family:{{item.fontFamily}}">{{item.text}}</div>
```

Moreover, i need that these fonts will be shown in android as a platform that connects between web and android.
Are the safeweb fonts are cross-platformed?

Answer (score 0):

I found this list : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_family_(HTML)

I hope that it is good enough.